# Can any irrational number become rational by inserting digits?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Here are the rules:

1. You are given a decimal irrational number.
2. You may (only if you want) insert ONE SINGLE digit between each two digits of the given irrational number.
3. Your task is to make it rational.

For example:
If he given irrational is:
0.99090090009...

You can insert 9's and 0's to make it rational:
0.90909090909...

Is it always possible?

Conclusion: No.

Counterexaple: 0.0112223333...

Credits to: @lulu

Comment: What are your thoughts?  As a suggestion, I'd look at something with ever increasing blocks of single digits.  Like $.011222333344444555555\cdots$

Comment: How many digits can I add? Can I just add infinitely many 0s at the start to get 0.0000….=0?

Comment: If you can insert as many digits as you want, then you can make any sequence of digits into 01234567890123456789...

Comment: How are you getting from 0.11010010001... to  0.1010101010101... by inserting 1's?
You won't get rid of the first two adjacent 1's by inserting more 1's.

Comment: **Note**: The sum of any rational number and any irrational number will always be an irrational number.

Comment: For what it's worth, my reading of the problem was that you could add as many (or as few) digits as you liked, but you could only add at most a single digit between any two consecutive digits of the original.  Of course, the OP might have intended something different.  For instance, it's very different if you assume you are wriiting numbers in base $2$, though the OP doesn't mention that (the given example is binary though).

Comment: @RobertIsrael  I'd have said that the OP meant $.1\underline {0}1010\underline {1}\cdots$, where the underlined  numbers represent the numbers being inserted.  Indeed, if the number is binary you can always get one of $.\overline {10}$ or $.\overline {01}$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this mistake @RobertIsrael. I meant 1's and 0's. Also, the given irrational number is in decimal form, although the example could be binary as well.

Comment: I suggest:  edit your post for clarity.  As you can see from the comments, people aren't clear what you are asking.

Comment: Are you also allowed to not insert a digit at some positions? If there are only $0$ and $1$ in the digits, you can insert $0$ between every $11$ and $1$ between every $00$ and not change $01$ or $10.$

Comment: Post edit, that appears to match my reading of the problem, right?  But then I think the decimal I gave in my first comment  is a counterexample.  After all, if the periodic block had length $n$ then any fixed digit would have to occupy at least half of the periodic block (as the original contains strings of $n$ consecutive instances of that digit for all $n$), which is clearly not possible in base $10$.  Works in binary though.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, you are allowed not to insert as well.

Comment: @lulu Yes, exactly.

Comment: So...you agree with my counterexample?

Comment: No, I meant your reading of the problem is right. I don't see yet why isn't it possible in base 10 to have a fixed digit occupying half of the periodic block.

Comment: *Any* fixed digit.  Thus half or more of the periodic block must be $0's$, AND half or more must be $1's$, AND half or more must be $2's$ and so on.  Thus in any base bigger than base $2$ you can't do it.

Comment: I see. Great job. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

If the base is bigger than $2$, you can't guarantee being able to do this.

A counterexample is $\alpha= .011222000011111222222\cdots$ where the digits cycle forever in blocks that increase by one each time.

To see that this is a counterexample, suppose that you had successfully made this rational, and that the length of the periodic block of the rational is $n$.  Then fix a digit $d\in \{0,1,2\}$ and look at one of the blocks of the digit $d$ of length $>n$ in $\alpha$.  In your rationalized version, the image of that string must contain a periodic block.  Now, you might have inserted a different digit in between two consecutive $d's$, but at leaast half of that periodic block must be $d's$.  However, that can't hold for all three digits simultaneously, so we have a contradiction.

In binary it's different.  If your number starts with a $1$, say, then you can always produce $.\overline {10}$.